# How to import two or more Excel data or files to Gridview

Tags: excel, vb.net

I want to import two or more Excel files into GridView but only import and read the first Excel file, it does not import two files. How can Import more Excel data?

Import Two or more Excel files
[image]

Import 2 or more Excel files
[image]

This is an example of Import:

```
            Dim conn As OleDbConnection
            Dim dta As OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim dts As DataSet
            Dim Excel As String
            Dim OpenFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog
            OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\Test"
            OpenFileDialog.Multiselect = True
            OpenFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|Xls Files (*.xls)|*.xls"
            If OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
                Dim Filename As String = OpenFileDialog.FileName
                Excel = fi.FullName
                conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Excel + "; 
                Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
                dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet$]", conn)
                dts = New DataSet
                dta.Fill(dts, "[Sheet$]")
                GridControl1.DataSource = dts
                GridControl1.DataMember = "[Sheet$]"
                conn.Close()
            End If
```

Can it Import more Excel files to GridView?

Comment: What if the two excel files have different columns?

Comment: Would you be okay with reading the file information into a Class? If so you could create a class containing the information of each row, then set a list of such class as DataSource to the GridControl. That means that you can import as many files as you would like and just keep stacking them.

Comment: Also is the program supposed to be saving information back to the excelsheets or is it read only?

Comment: And do you know that the `OpenFileDialog` has a `FileNames ()` array?

Comment: I don't know what `FileNames ()` means or does, after opening one file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to call `GetFiles` in the `Form.Load` and call `DisplayNextFile` in a `Button.Click`.

The code creates a list of the files and keeps track of what the next file is with the index field. In the command text I changed `[Sheet$]` to `[Sheet1$]`. Sheet1 is the default sheet name. If you don't have the default name or you have more than one sheet you will have to expand your code to retrieve the sheet names in each file.

The `Using...End Using` block ensures that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error. In this case both the connection and the command are included in a single block (note the comma after the first line of the Using).

```
Private files As New List(Of String)
Private index As Integer

Private Sub GetFiles()
    Dim OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\Test"
    OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = True
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|Xls Files (*.xls)|*.xls"
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK Then
        files = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.ToList
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DisplayNextFile()
    If index > files.Count - 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("The last file has been displayed")
        Return
    End If
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & files(index) & "; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", conn)
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    index += 1
End Sub
```

Comment: but where do I set the `button`? `Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button.Click`

Comment: Just add a button to your form in design view. Name the button btnDisplayFile and set the Text property to Display Next File.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I did a quick read on what options you have and I figure Merge on a DataSet is on point. So I use the FileNames() opening that @preciousbetine mentioned in the comments to fetch all file names selected. Then I did a simple merge of each file that was fetched. Code example below:

```
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection
    Dim dta As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dts As DataSet = Nothing
    Dim mainDts As DataSet = Nothing
    Dim Excel As String
    Dim OpenFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog
    OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\Test"
    OpenFileDialog.Multiselect = True
    OpenFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|Xls Files (*.xls)|*.xls"
    If OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK Then
        For Each fileName As String In OpenFileDialog.FileNames
            Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(fileName)
            Excel = fi.FullName
            conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Excel + "; 
            Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
            dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet$]", conn)
            dts = New DataSet
            dta.Fill(dts, "[Sheet$]")

            conn.Close()
            If mainDts Is Nothing Then
                mainDts = dts
            Else
                mainDts.Merge(dts)
            End If
        Next
        DataGridView1.DataSource = mainDts
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "[Sheet$]"
    End If
```